# Remembering window workspace between Unity sessions

Tags: unity, google-chrome, compiz, workspaces, viewports

When I log in to Ubuntu I have 6 workspaces set up in Unity/compiz. On four of those workspaces I place a chrome window, in another RStudio, and another just has a few Terminals. I also have pidgin on the RHS of each workspace (sticky).

When I log in the next time I'd like to be able to run something which:

a - places the programs I always use (Terminal, chrome, Rstudio) on the correct workspace;
b - fixes their dimensions (when I switch laptop between external screen and internal screen Unity changes the workspace - see [Switching displays while keeping windows in workspaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172712/switching-displays-while-keeping-windows-in-workspaces));

Is there a way to record window size and workspace so I can write a shell script to restore my preferred setup ?

The solution should (if possible) work with chrome in particular.

There is a partial answer to this, pointed out by Jacob - [Is there a script (or software) to open an application window on a specific viewport and position?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621721/is-there-a-script-or-software-to-open-an-application-window-on-a-specific-view) - but that is targeted at opening up the same set of windows each time, rather than recording a particular setup and then restoring that. It therefore solves some of my problems, but not the full restoration of chrome windows (with tabs) which were open at the time I saved  the session.

I think that is down to me imperfectly explaining the issue - I think the solution found by Jacob sorts out the problem I identified, so will accept and come back to this if I need the other element sorted.

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a script (or software) to open an application window on a specific viewport and position?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/621721/is-there-a-script-or-software-to-open-an-application-window-on-a-specific-view)

Comment: Please leave a comment if you (don't) manage.

Comment: Have edited the question to explain that it partially solves my problem, but fully solves the problem as written.

Comment: I remember there is another option on webupd8 somewhere, I'll look it up, but I am on mobile atm :)